# How does "pause(n)" work in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I'm using MATLAB to read from a serial port. A colleague of mine is doing the same thing with LabVIEW. He told me that I needed a pause in my code to allow the system time to write the data back. However, I've read that "pause(n)" halts execution for n seconds.

I'm not totally sure what it means by "halts execution." Does is stop the serial port from reading and writing, therefore nullifying my purpose?

Should I use another function, or should pause(n) be okay for my purposes?

Comment: Use drawnow to flush various things, without pausing. However, are you sure it's needed? Have you tried something and it doesn't work?

Comment: You may be better off listening to the "datareceived" event of your serial port object and assign a callback to read the buffer when the event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pause(n)` basically makes your program sleep for `n` seconds.  As such, when you invoke `pause`, it makes your program wait there for `n` seconds, then proceeds to the next line of code.

For example:

```
a = rand(3,3);
pause(2); % // Pause for 2 seconds
b = rand(4,4);
```

This creates a random `3 x 3` matrix stored in `a`, then the program **waits** at the second line for two seconds.  The program does nothing and sleeps.  After, a `4 x 4` random matrix is created.

To answer your question, this does **not** stop the serial port.  All you're doing is allowing the data enough time to be written to the serial port before you decide to write more to the port.  Similarly, you're allowing the serial port enough time to buffer enough data to the port so you can read the right amount of bytes in one read.